# QGIS Zonal Histogram failure on high resolution multispectral orthomosaics

Tags: qgis, raster, zonal-statistics, statistics, histogram

I'm trying to run zonal histograms on high resolution multispectral orthos collected via drone. I'm trying do do vegetation assessments on crop, and when I run the QGIS zonal histogram function it always freezes the program up. I assume its because the the very large number of pixels in the raster layer. For example when I compute the zonal statistics I am getting a count of 4 million. But even if I just run the zonal histogram on a single small area I still get QGIS crashing. I've tried having the output as a shapefile, csv, xlsx and that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Is there was a way to limit the number of unique values in the histogram? Like for example NDVI data has range of 0 to 1. So I would love to be able to run the zonal histogram but only have 100 columns from 0-1 rather than a column for each unique pixel value on the entire raster. Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: Seems that you should only be getting 256 different values since the tool requires a band number as an input to the tool when using a multi-band raster.  Maybe post a picture of your zonal histogram inputs?

Comment: I was getting pixels with a large number of decimals which is why I had so many uniques - I'm going to try "reclassify raster by table" and make my reclassifications based on the mean +/- the standard deviation of the data based on the zonal statistics report.